Gradle plugin 8.3.2: Adding build configs
I am on android gradle plugin version 8.3.2. I am trying to configure different constants for my release and dev builds. I am not using productFlavors because this doesn't change the behavriour of the app. Below is my build types section
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            manifestPlaceholders["appName"] = "Foo"
            buildConfigField "String" "MY_TOKEN" "${myTokenRelease}"


        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            manifestPlaceholders["appName"] = "FooDebug"
            buildConfigField "String" "MY_TOKEN" "${myTokenDebug}"


        }
    }

I tried clean build, invalidate caches and restart, but I get the error
Gradle DSL method not found: buildConfigField()

What is the solution for this? I would like to try "buildConfigFields" which takes a Map<String, ClassField> as a parameter. I am not sure how to construct a ClassField.

Maybe the fact that you have buildConfigFields (notice the 's') in release and buildConfigField (notice the non-existence of an 's') in debug? (BTW, this field has been deprecated in 8.4 and will be removed in 9.0 ...)

@dominicoder sorry that was a typo in the question. What is the alternative to this field?

Oh - it may not actually be deprecated, the gradle property the upgrade assistant itself added is deprecated ... It requires a new way to enable it. See this answer. Why the upgrade assistant didn't just do this is beyond me ...
